# Add HTML file into SQLite Database

Tags: objective-c, html, uisearchbar

I want to add html file into my sqlite database. And also want to fetch data from html file to  my app. I want this by using searchbar functionality. Any help is appriciated?? Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can upload files to physical location and add a file path to the database. This would be the appropriate way.